# Haskell function type generalization

Tags: haskell, types

I am studying a Haskell course since I am total beginner. There is a task which I am not able to solve although I tried many times.

The task is to determine the most general type of following function:

```
f x _ False = x
f _ x y     = maybe 42 (g y) x
```

providing we know that   `g :: a -> [a] -> b`

Can anyone help me? Thank you

I tried to determine `y :: Bool, g :: Bool -> [Bool] -> b(?)`
But I am not sure what should be "x" 'cause from the first row we could say that it can be `maybe 42 (g y) x` but there is another "x" in the expression.

So maybe the type of the `f` is `f :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> Bool -> [Bool]`?

Comment: Ugh, this is such an idiotic exercise, I wish people giving Haskell lecture would stop giving these.

Answer (score 4):

Let us start with the most generic type possible: the function takes three parameters, and thus returns an item, so we assume first that `f` has type:

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

We see that the third parameter matches with `False` so that is a `Bool`, so `c ~ Bool`. The first clause also assigns the first parameter to `x` and returns `x`, so that means that the type `a` of the first parameter, and that of the return type `d` is the same, so `a ~ d`.

We know that `maybe` has type `maybe :: f -> (e -> f) -> Maybe e -> f`, and `42` is the first parameter so has type `f`. An integer literal can have any `Num` type, so we know `Num f`. Since the return type of `maybe 42 (g y) x` is also `f` and we know that this is also `a`, we know that `f ~ a`, so we can "specialize" `maybe` in this case to `maybe :: Num a => a -> (e -> a) -> Maybe e -> a`. The third parameter in `maybe 42 (g y) x` is `x`, this is the *second* parameter in the `f` call (not to be confused with the first clause), so we know that `b ~ Maybe e`.

We also see a call `g y` with `g :: g -> [g] -> h`. The type of `g y` should match that of the second parameter of the `maybe` call, so that means that `e ~ [g]` and `a ~ h`. `y` has type `Bool` in the `g y` call, so that means that `g ~ Bool`, and thus the `g` function has type `g :: Bool -> [Bool] -> a`.

Now we thus have gathered the following types and equivalences:

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
maybe :: f -> (e -> f) -> Maybe e -> f
g :: g -> [g] -> h
a ~ d
c ~ Bool
Num f
f ~ a
b ~ Maybe e
g ~ Bool
e ~ [g]
a ~ h
g ~ Bool
```

This thus means that `f` has type:

```
   f :: a -> b -> c -> d
-> f :: a -> b -> c -> a
-> f :: a -> b -> Bool -> a
-> f :: Num f => f -> b -> Bool -> f
-> f :: Num f => f -> Maybe e -> Bool -> f
-> f :: Num f => f -> Maybe [g] -> Bool -> f
-> f :: Num f => f -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> f
```

Hence the most generic type is `f :: Num f => f -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> f`, or we can rename the parameters to `f :: Num a => a -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> a`.

We can let `ghci` do the work, for example with:

```
ghci> import Data.Maybe
ghci> :{
ghci| g :: a -> [a] -> b
ghci| g = undefined
ghci| :}
ghci> :{
ghci| f x _ False = x
ghci| f _ x y     = maybe 42 (g y) x
ghci| :}
ghci> :t f
f :: Num p => p -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> p
```

This thus means that `ghci` confirms this type.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realize is that, for any equation, any variables defined in that equation, are scoped only to that equation. In particular, this means that the `x` on the first line is not related at all to the `x` on the second line. These are two separate variables, they just happen to have the same name.

Now, you have already correctly determined that `y :: Bool` and `g :: Bool -> [Bool] -> b` for some as of yet unknown `b`. And therefore, `g y :: [Bool] -> b`

The next thing to observe is that, since `maybe :: p -> (q -> p) -> Maybe q -> p`, which means that `q ~ [Bool]` (coming from the type of `g y`) and `p ~ Int` (coming from the literal `42`). And therefore, `g :: Bool -> [Bool] -> Int` and `x :: Maybe [Bool]` (since it's used as the third parameter of `maybe`).

Finally, from the second equation, we can see that the function's return type is whatever `maybe` returns, which is `Int`. And therefore, that's also the type of the first parameter, because it's being returned in the first equation.

Taking all of that together:

```
f :: Int -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> Int
```

One final stroke: I actually lied a little. The literal `42` is not really `Int`. Such literal can be any type that has an instance of the `Num` class. To account for that, let's replace our `Int`s in the signature with a generic type and give that type a `Num` constraint:

```
f :: Num a => a -> Maybe [Bool] -> Bool -> a
```